# pygame GUI python3.6

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I have been struggling with this for a while and want to ask. I downloaded pygame GUI from https://github.com/ddorn/GUI . Basically the problem is when you try to use it this error occurs:

```
if e.key == K_RIGHT:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
```

I tried changing the `e.key` to `o.key` but nothing happened. The same error popped up. I tried to contact the author but failed. Please help.

Comment: What is `e`? What is the context of your code fragment?

Comment: The e.key is in for loop you are basically setting e to an pygame.event.get().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame events are quite easy. Use them that way :

```
for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("Right Arrow Key")
```

Note that you mustnt forget `pygame.init()` , and after run, `pygame.quit()`